# Java Program to determine value of nested radical constant with 10^-6 precision

Tags: java, matlab, math

Nested radical constant is defined as:

[image: nested radical constant]

I am writing a Java program to calculate the value of nested radical constant with 10^-6 precision and also print the number of iterations required to get to that precision. Here is my code:

```
public class nested_radical {

public nested_radical() {
    int n = 1;

    while ((loop(n) - loop(n - 1)) > 10e-6) {
        n++;
    }
    System.out.println("value of given expression = " + loop(n));
    System.out.println("Iterations required = " + n);
}

public double loop(int n) {
    double sum = 0;
    while (n > 0) {
        sum = Math.sqrt(sum + n--);
    }
    return (sum);
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    new nested_radical();
}

}
```

This code does what it is supposed to but it is slow. What should I do to optimize this program? Can someone suggest another possible way to implement this program?

I also want to write a same kind of program in MATLAB. It would be great if someone could translate this program into MATLAB too.

Comment: You could make it twice as fast by simply remembering `loop(n - 1)` instead of recomputing it.

Comment: See also the same question on math.se https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2027412/115115 . Going to `n=15` or so should not be that slow.

Comment: Please explain in what way or under which circumstances the code is slow. How did you measure it?

Comment: Well, I didn't really measure it. I just noticed that this program took around 2-3 seconds to print the output. That's why I thought it's slow.

Comment: I think remembering `loop(n - 1)` is a good idea. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made some changes in this code and now it stores the value of `loop(n - 1)` instead of computing it every time. Now this program seems much optimized than before.

```
public class nested_radical {

public nested_radical() {
    int n = 1;
    double x = 0, y = 0, p = 1;
    while ( p > 10e-6) { 
        y=x;             /*stored the value of loop(n - 1) instead of recomputing*/
        x = loop(n);
        p = x - y;
        n++;
    }
    System.out.println("value of given expression = " + x);
    System.out.println("Iterations required = " + n);
}

public double loop(int n) {
    double sum = 0;
    while (n > 0) {
        sum = Math.sqrt(sum + n--);
    }
    return (sum);
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    new nested_radical();
}

}
```

I also successfully translated this code in MATLAB. Here is the code for MATLAB:

```
n = 1;
x = 0;
p = 1;
while(p > 10e-6)
    y = x;
    sum = 0;
    m=n;
    while (m > 0)
        sum = sqrt(sum + m);
        m = m - 1;
    end
    x = sum;
    p = (x-y);
    n = n + 1;
end
fprintf('Value of given expression: %.16f\n', x);
fprintf('Iterations required: %d\n', n);
```